# Why does this NodeJS code leak memory?

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks

I have a NodeJS application which uses a module, `stats`. The `stats` module is meant to keep track of essentially just rates: number of requests per second, etc. This all seemed fairly straightforward until I tried putting this code in production. When in a deployed environment this code leaks, and quite badly. Removing this code and the leak disappears. I'm very confused about why this is happening as there is no obvious memory leak to me. Please bear in mind that I'm decently new to JavaScript so there may be a nuance here that I'm missing as related to memory allocation and reclamation.

Here's the stats module:

```
// stats.js
const meters = {};


class ExponentiallyWeightedMovingAverage {
  constructor(timePeriod = 1000 * 60, tickInterval = 1000 * 5) {
    this.timePeriod = timePeriod;
    this.tickInterval = tickInterval;

    this.alpha = 1 - Math.exp(-this.tickInterval / this.timePeriod);
    this.count = 0;
    this.rate = 0;

    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
  }

  update(n) {
    this.count += n;
  }

  tick() {
    const instantRate = this.count / this.tickInterval;
    this.count = 0;

    this.rate += (this.alpha * (instantRate - this.rate));
  }

  getRate(timeUnit) {
    return this.rate * timeUnit;
  }
}


function meter(name) {
  if (name in meters) {
    return meters[name];
  }

  const rateUnit = 1000;
  const tickInterval = 5 * 1000;

  const m1Rate = new ExponentiallyWeightedMovingAverage(1 * 60 * 1000, tickInterval);
  const m5Rate = new ExponentiallyWeightedMovingAverage(5 * 60 * 1000, tickInterval);
  const m15Rate = new ExponentiallyWeightedMovingAverage(15 * 60 * 1000, tickInterval);

  let count = 0;

  function mark(n = 1) {
    count += n;
    m1Rate.update(n);
    m5Rate.update(n);
    m15Rate.update(n);
  }

  function tick() {
    m1Rate.tick();
    m5Rate.tick();
    m15Rate.tick();
  }

  setInterval(tick, tickInterval);

  function meterToJSON() {
    return {
      count,
      '1MinuteRate': m1Rate.getRate(rateUnit),
      '5MinuteRate': m5Rate.getRate(rateUnit),
      '15MinuteRate': m15Rate.getRate(rateUnit),
    };
  }

  meters[name] = { mark, toJSON: meterToJSON };
  return meters[name];
}


function toJSON() {
  const objs = {};

  Object.entries(meters).forEach(([name, storedMeter]) => {
    const obj = {};
    obj[name] = storedMeter.toJSON();
    Object.assign(objs, obj);
  });

  return objs;
}


const global = { meter, toJSON };

module.exports = { global };
```

Now this gets used in a Connect middleware in my Node app. Essentially like this:

```
// middleware/collect-stats.js
import stats from '../stats';

...

const host = 'www.example.com';
stats.global.meter(`originLatency${host}`).mark(time);
```

And again a bit later on in the middleware chain:

```
// middleware/proxy-req.js
import stats from '../stats';

...

const currentStats = stats.global.toJSON();
const latency = currentStats['originLatencywww.example.com'];
console.log(latency['1MinuteRate']);
```

I simplified how the latency is actually consumed here a bit, but that's the gist of what's going on.

Is there any reason for this code to leak? Why would this max out memory on my EC2 instances, causing them to eventually crash?

Note that in production this is running on EC2 in a Docker container via FROM node:7.4, i.e. Node 7.4. (It's the leak is much worse on 7.6.)

Comment: Downvoters add comments to help the developer what he missed.  Otherwise please don't downvote.

Comment: may be appropriate to post in codereview exchange site?

Comment: @Rao no. CR for code that works as intended, and not for "why is my code not working" (in this case leaking).